# Spring WS security-accessing keystore that is not on the class path

Tags: spring, security, soap, spring-ws

I am new to spring web services and am currently trying to implement spring-ws security for secure transport and encryption/decryption of incoming and outgoing SOAP messages. We have a keystore on our server that is installed in the conf directory under Tomcat. How do I reference that keystore in my spring web app? I'd like to avoid having to move the keystore since it will be utilized by other applications in the future. I've searched for answers most of yesterday, but all the examples I've come across put the keystore file on the class path.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using WSS4J with Spring-WS, you can put any valid [resource](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/resources.html#resources-implementations) to refer to the certificate location.
eg.

```
<property name="keyStoreLocation" value="file://C:/tomcat/.."/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I didn't know you could use a file reference like the (I'm new to spring also). For spring-ws security, I am using XWSS.